# Clients (Browser) goes timeout while connecting to a SSLSocket with CA certified certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I am having the problem, where the clients (browsers) goes timeout while connecting to the SSLSocket which has a keystore having a CA signed certificate.

My SSLServer Code is as follows:

```
static{
    try {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
        //Security.addProvider(new Provider());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","true");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:/cert/hello.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","****");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(443);
        //serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);

        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
        serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(524288);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the code, which accepts connection is as follow:

```
clientSocket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println(clientSocket);
                clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
                //clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                clientSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(524288);
```

But unfortunately, when i try to connect on port 443 for that ip from browser, like say 
`https://ip:443` it goes timeout

After A few changes to the KeyStore, i am now getting the Remote Host closed connection error when i am trying to flush something to the clientSocket, like at the line:

```
clinetSocket.flush
```

And i get the following exception:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handsh
ake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
        at com.xxx.yyy.SocketSubscribe.run(SocketSubscribe.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        ... 11 more
```

The following is the javax.net.ssl debug logs, though i am not an expert in understanding the log, just after `GET /rest/whoami` it is showing socket is closed, not sure which part of the code is closing the socket:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Server Socket Buffer Size: 524288
Protocols: [Ljava.lang.String;@56af5047
Cipher Suites:  [Ljava.lang.String;@fbf91c7
69fba7e4[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=56797,localport=443]]
Thread-2, setSoTimeout(0) called
Client Socket Buffer Size: 524288
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 D2                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 210
0000: 01 00 00 CE 03 02 29 75   83 35 84 F8 E7 3B 32 97  ......)u.5...;2.
0010: 81 DD 54 10 FD 29 E8 05   72 ED 8C BC 11 B6 39 9C  ..T..)..r.....9.
0020: A8 93 FE 73 43 86 20 54   4B 96 FC 0D B8 56 E2 EE  ...sC. TK....V..
0030: 88 A6 05 ED 82 3E B2 C2   10 74 6C F0 68 4B 91 B3  .....>...tl.hK..
0040: 3D 8A FA 33 35 6F 88 00   28 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9E CC  =..35o..(.+./...
0050: 14 CC 13 C0 0A C0 09 C0   13 C0 14 C0 07 C0 11 00  ................
0060: 33 00 32 00 39 00 9C 00   2F 00 35 00 0A 00 05 00  3.2.9.../.5.....
0070: 04 01 00 00 5D 00 00 00   0E 00 0C 00 00 09 6C 6F  ....].........lo
0080: 63 61 6C 68 6F 73 74 FF   01 00 01 00 00 0A 00 08  calhost.........
0090: 00 06 00 17 00 18 00 19   00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 23  ...............#
00A0: 00 00 33 74 00 00 00 10   00 1B 00 19 06 73 70 64  ..3t.........spd
00B0: 79 2F 33 08 73 70 64 79   2F 33 2E 31 08 68 74 74  y/3.spdy/3.1.htt
00C0: 70 2F 31 2E 31 00 05 00   05 01 00 00 00 00 00 12  p/1.1...........
00D0: 00 00                                              ..
Thread-2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 210
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 695501621 bytes = { 132, 248, 231, 59, 50, 151, 129, 221, 84, 16, 253, 41, 232, 5, 114, 237, 140, 188, 17, 182, 57, 156, 168, 147, 254, 115, 67, 134 }
Session ID:  {84, 75, 150, 252, 13, 184, 86, 226, 238, 136, 166, 5, 237, 130, 62, 178, 194, 16, 116, 108, 240, 104, 75, 145, 179, 61, 138, 250, 51, 53, 111, 136}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, Unknown 0xcc:0x14, Unknown 0xcc:0x13, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: localhost]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:19:06:73:70:64:79:2f:33:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 210
0000: 01 00 00 CE 03 02 29 75   83 35 84 F8 E7 3B 32 97  ......)u.5...;2.
0010: 81 DD 54 10 FD 29 E8 05   72 ED 8C BC 11 B6 39 9C  ..T..)..r.....9.
0020: A8 93 FE 73 43 86 20 54   4B 96 FC 0D B8 56 E2 EE  ...sC. TK....V..
0030: 88 A6 05 ED 82 3E B2 C2   10 74 6C F0 68 4B 91 B3  .....>...tl.hK..
0040: 3D 8A FA 33 35 6F 88 00   28 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9E CC  =..35o..(.+./...
0050: 14 CC 13 C0 0A C0 09 C0   13 C0 14 C0 07 C0 11 00  ................
0060: 33 00 32 00 39 00 9C 00   2F 00 35 00 0A 00 05 00  3.2.9.../.5.....
0070: 04 01 00 00 5D 00 00 00   0E 00 0C 00 00 09 6C 6F  ....].........lo
0080: 63 61 6C 68 6F 73 74 FF   01 00 01 00 00 0A 00 08  calhost.........
0090: 00 06 00 17 00 18 00 19   00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 23  ...............#
00A0: 00 00 33 74 00 00 00 10   00 1B 00 19 06 73 70 64  ..3t.........spd
00B0: 79 2F 33 08 73 70 64 79   2F 33 2E 31 08 68 74 74  y/3.spdy/3.1.htt
00C0: 70 2F 31 2E 31 00 05 00   05 01 00 00 00 00 00 12  p/1.1...........
00D0: 00 00                                              ..
%% Resuming [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1414174480 bytes = { 24, 194, 29, 184, 17, 188, 176, 74, 202, 134, 74, 228, 87, 199, 127, 151, 215, 71, 48, 249, 57, 34, 104, 251, 39, 138, 66, 110 }
Session ID:  {84, 75, 150, 252, 13, 184, 86, 226, 238, 136, 166, 5, 237, 130, 62, 178, 194, 16, 116, 108, 240, 104, 75, 145, 179, 61, 138, 250, 51, 53, 111, 136}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 29 75 83 35 84 F8 E7 3B   32 97 81 DD 54 10 FD 29  )u.5...;2...T..)
0010: E8 05 72 ED 8C BC 11 B6   39 9C A8 93 FE 73 43 86  ..r.....9....sC.
Server Nonce:
0000: 54 4B 97 10 18 C2 1D B8   11 BC B0 4A CA 86 4A E4  TK.........J..J.
0010: 57 C7 7F 97 D7 47 30 F9   39 22 68 FB 27 8A 42 6E  W....G0.9"h.'.Bn
Master Secret:
0000: B5 87 A5 75 CE 80 96 41   D6 44 EE 25 8B CE 58 F7  ...u...A.D.%..X.
0010: 9D 5A 7C 6D 21 25 B8 4B   6F 0D 0F ED E4 45 45 27  .Z.m!%.Ko....EE'
0020: 79 55 9B 23 B0 DF 55 41   A4 ED 4E 54 F0 F0 E9 BD  yU.#..UA..NT....
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: D6 C2 97 B5 6B 0E 30 5C   74 E3 97 74 4F 08 DA 7B  ....k.0\t..tO...
0010: DC 2B 2F DA                                        .+/.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: C3 4D 73 9B FB D5 F4 B2   0F 6A 9D 78 0C 69 2F D4  .Ms......j.x.i/.
0010: 01 8C 10 5C                                        ...\
Client write key:
0000: 94 4B 87 12 E0 22 1A 12   EF 1E B6 FC 92 34 9E 5A  .K...".......4.Z
Server write key:
0000: 52 6B E1 F0 75 7B A8 40   D1 05 8C 0A AB 45 09 39  Rk..u..@.....E.9
... no IV derived for this protocol
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 02 54 4B   97 10 18 C2 1D B8 11 BC  ...M..TK........
0010: B0 4A CA 86 4A E4 57 C7   7F 97 D7 47 30 F9 39 22  .J..J.W....G0.9"
0020: 68 FB 27 8A 42 6E 20 54   4B 96 FC 0D B8 56 E2 EE  h.'.Bn TK....V..
0030: 88 A6 05 ED 82 3E B2 C2   10 74 6C F0 68 4B 91 B3  .....>...tl.hK..
0040: 3D 8A FA 33 35 6F 88 C0   13 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  =..35o..........
0050: 00                                                 .
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 81
[Raw write]: length = 86
0000: 16 03 02 00 51 02 00 00   4D 03 02 54 4B 97 10 18  ....Q...M..TK...
0010: C2 1D B8 11 BC B0 4A CA   86 4A E4 57 C7 7F 97 D7  ......J..J.W....
0020: 47 30 F9 39 22 68 FB 27   8A 42 6E 20 54 4B 96 FC  G0.9"h.'.Bn TK..
0030: 0D B8 56 E2 EE 88 A6 05   ED 82 3E B2 C2 10 74 6C  ..V.......>...tl
0040: F0 68 4B 91 B3 3D 8A FA   33 35 6F 88 C0 13 00 00  .hK..=..35o.....
0050: 05 FF 01 00 01 00                                  ......
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 02 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 57, 238, 77, 236, 77, 135, 122, 59, 25, 135, 211, 216 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 39 EE 4D EC   4D 87 7A 3B 19 87 D3 D8  ....9.M.M.z;....
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 64
0000: 35 E9 9F 49 C4 FE BF AE   8B 55 4C 70 04 C5 C0 42  5..I.....ULp...B
0010: 14 00 00 0C 39 EE 4D EC   4D 87 7A 3B 19 87 D3 D8  ....9.M.M.z;....
0020: 28 85 41 30 DF F1 D2 42   74 EB 3E 82 1B 6D CC 4C  (.A0...Bt.>..m.L
0030: 4B 6E 80 4A 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  Kn.J............
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 64
[Raw write]: length = 69
0000: 16 03 02 00 40 C9 9A 9A   D1 82 A2 AC 60 FA 4F 43  ....@.......`.OC
0010: DD 57 43 32 4A BF 92 8A   12 65 F0 16 CB 16 4F B5  .WC2J....e....O.
0020: 23 96 F2 48 C6 A9 4D 06   27 49 61 C5 53 80 77 D5  #..H..M.'Ia.S.w.
0030: 8A 1F B4 B6 DA 0C 25 E4   D8 DD A7 47 43 3D 0C 70  ......%....GC=.p
0040: B0 19 78 BA 73                                     ..x.s
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 02 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
Thread-2, READ: TLSv1.1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 02 00 40                                     ....@
[Raw read]: length = 64
0000: 72 4A F7 CA 9B A0 57 47   EB CE 9B DF D1 E4 2D A5  rJ....WG......-.
0010: 2F FE 67 96 4C 1A F6 56   D4 1F 1E 48 4F 64 86 4A  /.g.L..V...HOd.J
0020: 6A F7 BB 2F 87 C0 A3 CA   F0 39 C7 90 B2 E2 35 F4  j../.....9....5.
0030: 44 AE 64 D3 FF A8 C5 30   84 3A 0B 34 AE 84 F6 B9  D.d....0.:.4....
Thread-2, READ: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 64
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 64
0000: D2 BC DF 8A 80 40 10 DE   90 A1 D5 8A E0 B8 04 F9  .....@..........
0010: 14 00 00 0C 66 BD BC 35   7E 3D 7A 93 03 0B B6 64  ....f..5.=z....d
0020: B1 55 14 B8 5B 29 80 B4   0D 8F BE 97 39 79 86 B4  .U..[)......9y..
0030: 99 6E 5F E9 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  .n_.............
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 102, 189, 188, 53, 126, 61, 122, 147, 3, 11, 182, 100 }
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 66 BD BC 35   7E 3D 7A 93 03 0B B6 64  ....f..5.=z....d
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 96
0000: 4B C0 CC 7C AA 1F 07 E5   55 CF 3E D9 5C F3 29 29  K.......U.>.\.))
0010: 47 45 54 20 2F 72 65 73   74 2F 77 68 6F 61 6D 69  GET /rest/whoami
0020: 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E   31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A   HTTP/1.1..Host:
0030: 20 6E 75 6C 6C 3A 38 30   0D 0A 0D 0A 82 83 A4 49   null:80.......I
0040: 06 82 C4 7B 0C 30 66 1F   59 1A 55 E8 25 2A 1F 5C  .....0f.Y.U.%*.\
0050: 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F   0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F  ................
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 96
[Raw write]: length = 101
0000: 17 03 02 00 60 94 99 04   5E DD 65 08 26 C1 E9 EF  ....`...^.e.&...
0010: 04 A6 9A 75 4D 1E 29 25   3B E2 6D 2B 7D 97 43 A2  ...uM.)%;.m+..C.
0020: BB 13 CA 05 92 9D 5A 8F   1C B5 DE FF 06 BE AA D7  ......Z.........
0030: 87 D8 8A DF B2 1D A4 D8   17 34 82 66 2A 45 44 19  .........4.f*ED.
0040: A1 14 86 43 E9 79 0B EB   1E 4F 76 DD FD 8F 8E E7  ...C.y...Ov.....
0050: 9D 63 A7 85 B4 BC BB 6D   B7 B1 A2 6B C9 85 18 D5  .c.....m...k....
0060: 52 B4 B6 6F 37                                     R..o7
Sent Request: GET /rest/whoami HTTP/1.1
Host: null:80

Response is null, returning
Thread-2, called close()
Thread-2, called closeInternal(true)
Thread-2, SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 65 95 C1 4A D3 F0 60 38   39 3E 42 88 E0 BB AC 89  e..J..`89>B.....
0010: 01 00 FF 2D FE 2D B1 0A   24 17 19 6A 1A CD FB 54  ...-.-..$..j...T
0020: 0E CA C6 C1 BF A8 09 09   09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09  ................
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 15 03 02 00 30 8B DC 0A   C6 99 93 A4 22 D0 A4 3E  ....0......."..>
0010: AE 6E 0D B1 33 AF 2E 1D   FB 48 52 5E 97 16 DD 1E  .n..3....HR^....
0020: 43 79 53 1F 87 FE AC 23   FE 2B E6 85 EC F3 03 B7  CyS....#.+......
0030: 02 07 65 6A 00                                     ..ej.
Thread-2, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
```

I wrote a client which eventually gets a request from the server. But when the client sends the response back to the Server. The server socket is already closed. I have also seen that, Since we are using TLS, the client sends two application messages which the server fails to decrypt, server sends an ALert 21 and drops the connection.

The client is as follows:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
 try {

     SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
     SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) 
     socketFactory.createSocket(new Socket("IP",443), "IP", 443, false);
     socket.startHandshake();
     socket.setKeepAlive(true);
     socket.setSoTimeout(0);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     System.out.println(in.readLine());
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
     out.write("I got the rest call whoami");
     out.flush();

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: There are too much possible reasons to answer this question, like no SSL server not listening because of permission problems, firewall issues, middleboxes etc. Please try with alternatives, i.e. another client (browser), another location etc to narrow the problem down. Also, do packet captures near the server to see if it gets accessed at all and if it hangs within TCP or SSL handshakes or later.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added the debug logs and a sample client which gets the message from the server but not able to send back. I have also added the java.net.ssl debug logs

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added the full Server Code, still not able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your debug output:

```
....
Sent Request: GET /rest/whoami HTTP/1.1
Host: null:80

Response is null, returning
Thread-2, called close()
Thread-2, called closeInternal(true)
Thread-2, SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
```

This means that the server successfully decrypts the request from the client. But it looks like that your server does not like the request so it creates no response and the connection gets closed without sending any data back. The `close_notify` alert is nothing to worry about, this is just part of the normal shutdown of a SSL connection.

Because you did not post any code which implements the application logic at the server side (that is the HTTP protocol part) I don't know what the server does not like from the clients request.

> I wrote a client which eventually gets a request from the server. But when the client sends the response back to the Server. The server socket is already closed.

I think you are a bit confused here. The client (browser) sends a (HTTP) request to the server (which you've implemented) and then the server has to parse the request and then send a (HTTP) response back to the client, not the other way around like you describe it.

Comment: What kind of protocol should this be? It is definitely not HTTP even if some strings refer to HTTP. Also, setting setNeedClientAuth should be done on the server socket. I would suggest that you strip your client and server down to a minimum to find your problem. At least I'm unable to understand what you are trying to achieve with this code and the non-existing documentation does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is late. But I consulted your post, and got success. So, I think I should put my code her, if it can help you.

First, I created a KeyStore with the Java Tool, keygen (ignore *):
keytool -genkey -alias *key_name* -keyalg RSA -keypass *key_password* -storepass *keystore_password* -keystore *keystore_path(.jks)*

Then I used:

```
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Class clase = this.getClass();        
        InputStream inputstream = clase.getResourceAsStream("/recursos/0.0.properties");
        properties.load(inputstream);
            System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
            javax_net_debug = properties.getProperty("javax_net_debug");
            if (javax_net_debug == null || javax_net_debug.isEmpty()) {
                javax_net_debug = System.getProperty("javax.net.debug");
            }
            if (javax_net_debug != null) {
                System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", javax_net_debug);
            }

            javax_net_ssl_keyStore = properties.getProperty("javax_net_ssl_keyStore");
            File file = new File (javax_net_ssl_keyStore);
            if (file.isAbsolute() == false) {
                URL url = clase.getResource("/");
                javax_net_ssl_keyStore = url.getPath() + javax_net_ssl_keyStore;
            }
            javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword = properties.getProperty("javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword");
            javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword = decodificar(javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword);
            if (javax_net_ssl_keyStore == null || javax_net_ssl_keyStore.isEmpty()) {
                javax_net_ssl_keyStore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
            }
            if (javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword == null || javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword.isEmpty()) {
                javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
            }
            if (javax_net_ssl_keyStore != null) {
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", javax_net_ssl_keyStore);
            }
            if (javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword != null) {
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", javax_net_ssl_keyStorePassword);
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String mensaje = e.getMessage();
        if (mensaje == null) {
            mensaje = "";
        }
        error[0] = "Error configuring SSL. " + mensaje;
        ret = false;
    }
```

After, I created the SSLServerSocket:

```
    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssl_server_socket_factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssl_server_socket_factory.createServerSocket();
        String[] protocols = sslserversocket.getSupportedProtocols();
        String[] protocols_enabled = sslserversocket.getEnabledProtocols();
        sslserversocket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        String[] suites = sslserversocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        String[] suites_default = ssl_server_socket_factory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        sslserversocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
        sslserversocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        InetSocketAddress socketaddress = new InetSocketAddress (puerto);
        sslserversocket.bind(socketaddress);
        serversocket = sslserversocket;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String mensaje = e.getMessage ();
        if (mensaje == null) {
            mensaje = "";
        }
        error [0] = "Error in SSLServerSocket. " + mensaje;
        ret = false;
    }
```

Finally, I had to do a double check for data input from the soket:

```
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) serversocket;
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
        Thread thread_socket = new Thread () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                try {
                    boolean ret = true;
                    String [] error = { "" };
                    InputStream inputstream = null;
                    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = null;
                    OutputStream outputstream = null;
                    inputstream = socket.getInputStream();
                    inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader (inputstream);
                    outputstream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    int tam_buffer = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                    char [] texto = new char [tam_buffer];
                    String lectura = "";
                    int tam = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        tam = inputstreamreader.read(texto);
                        if (tam >= 0) {
                            lectura = lectura + new String(texto,0, tam);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (inputstream.available() <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                     }
                     if (lectura.isEmpty() == false) {
                        Map <String, String> parametros_mapa = new HashMap ();
                        ret = procesar_input(lectura, outputstream, parametros_mapa, error);
                     }
                     inputstream.close();
                     outputstream.close();
                     socket.close();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     String mensaje = e.getMessage ();
                     if (mensaje == null) {
                        mensaje = "";
                     }
                     error [0] = "Connection ended. " + mensaje;
                 }
             }
         };
         thread_socket.start ();
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     String mensaje = e.getMessage ();
     if (mensaje == null) {
        mensaje = "";
     }
     error [0] = "Servidor finished. " + mensaje;
 }
 try {
     if (getServersocket() != null) {
        getServersocket().close();
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     String mensaje = e.getMessage ();
     if (mensaje == null) {
        mensaje = "";
     }
     error [0] = "Error closing ServerSocket. " + mensaje;
 }
```

}